# How can i implement the __getitem__ method in PyTorch for the sinus

Tags: python, pytorch

I am starting with PyTorch and i am trying to create a Network that is predicting the sinus of x. I tried to create a DataSet like this:

```
 class SinusDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, size: int = 1000):
        self.size = size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size


    def __getitem__(self, idx: int)->Tensor:
        if idx > self.size:
            raise ValueError
        
        return idx, math.sin(idx)
```

I do not think that is the proper way to implement this. How should I Implemented the `__get__´ method?

Comment: Raise `IndexError` instead of `ValueError`, and it looks fine to me. I don't know what  `Tensor` value is supposed to look like.

Comment: seems totally fine to me. what exactly is wrong with it ? you don't even need to place range check. PyTorch will take care of it through the use of `__len__()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could initialize your input and labels on init and save those in *list*s. Then, in your `__getitem__` function, pick instances from those two using the provided `idx` integer. Something like:

```
class SinusDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, size: int = 1000):
        self.x = torch.linspace(0, 1, size)
        self.y = torch.sin(self.x)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int):
        return return self.x[idx][None], self.y[idx][None]
```

Then you can use the dataset by wrapping a [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader):

```
>>> dl = DataLoader(SinusDataset(100), batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

>>> for x, y in dl:
...     print(x, y)
...     break
tensor([0.2452, 0.6116, 0.0791, 0.6667]) tensor([0.2428, 0.5742, 0.0790, 0.6184])
```

---

In this case it would be more appropriate to inherit from [`torch.utils.data.TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset) directly. This comes with both `__len__` and `__getitem__` implemented for you (see [*source*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/dataset.py#L246)):

```
class SinusDataset(TensorDataset):
    def __init__(self, size: int = 1000):
        x = torch.linspace(0, 1, 1000)[:,None]
        y = torch.sin(x)[:,None]
        super().__init__(x, y)
```

This is slightly more advanced but it is considered best practice to inherit from the closest built-in `torch.utils.data.Dataset` class instead of writing the same methods yourself.

---

Inference example:

```
>>> model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 4), 
                          nn.ReLU(), 
                          nn.Linear(4, 1))

>>> x, y = next(iter(dl))
>>> model(x)
tensor([[-0.0640],
        [ 0.1461],
        [-0.0882],
        [ 0.2259]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

Comment: So could I just do network(x) in the for loop or do I have to iterate over the batch?

Comment: You should infer with the whole batch yes, *i.e.* in the above example you can do `network(x)` directly.

Comment: I created a simple Network with a Linear(1, 4), ReLu() and a second Linear(4, 1) Layer. I get the RunTimError, that mat1 and mat2 cannot be multiplied (1x4 and 1x4). What could be Problem?

Comment: The dataset needs to return at least single-dimensional tensors, a broadcasting will make it work (see edit above).